# how is the attention width measure in SeqSelfAttention?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to initialize an attention width for a self attention layer, but I can't any description on how the width is measured in relation to the entire sequence input for my seqtoseq model.

I basically and initially starting with this but I have no clue what 15 actually means..?

model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_width=15, attention_activation='sigmoid'))